# Postman no reconoce la url del controlador asp net

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc, asp, controller

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial para la creacion de una API en ASP NET.
La solucion no trae la carpeta Controllers, asi que la cree yo, y agregue el controlador **CategoriasController**,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
agregue la ruta y siguiendo el tutorial quise testearla en Postman, pero no la reconoce :(
Solo reconoce la ruta: **https://localhost:7008/**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
pero no reconoce **https://localhost:7008/api/categorias**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta mal haber creado yo la carpeta de controladores?

Espero alguien pueda orientarme

Saludos :)

Comment: La mayoria de los proyectos asp, trae swagger incluido, que te ayuda con todo el tema de rutas y endpoints, y hasta te evita tener que usar postman...

Comment: de igual forma, tu ruta no es la que pensas.. Que hayas creado o no la carpeta controllers es indistinto (lo que hace a un controller que funcione asi, es justamente que herede de controller)...

Comment: mm entiendo, yo cree la carpeta herando de controller para quue al testear la api me arrojara los datos en postman, checare nuevamente la ruta

Comment: Qué tipo de template usaste para crear tu proyecto/solución? Tienes tu tabla de ruteo, algo así como 'app.MapControllerRoute(' en tu Program.cs?

Comment: en Program.cs solo tengo app.MapRazorPages(); solo cree la solucion normal

Answer (score 0):

Me di cuenta que habia utilizado la plantilla web en lugar de API, y tambien estaba mal en Program.cs
**Incorrecto:**

```js
builder.Services.AddDbContext < ApplicationDbContext > (options =>
  options.UseSqlServer("DefaultConnection"));
```

**Correcto:**

```js
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

ya que no tengo Startup.cs

Saludos!

Comment: Para futuras preguntas, incluye todo lo que sea necesario de tu escenario para que tengas mayor chance de obtener respuesta. Por otro lado, la cadena de conexión nada tiene que ver con el routing. Saludos. PD: Aquí una lectura sugerida para incrementar la calidad de las preguntas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822